# What do you call the large piece of leather worn around the waist like a belt in a kimono?

Tags: word-request

[image]

What do you call the large piece of leather worn around the waist like a belt in a kimono? I couldn't find the term for it. Is there a word for this?

Comment: It is called an obi, if it is Japanese. We just say a "heavy duty leather belt" but they look nothing like an obi and are generally used by workmen.

Comment: The belt in a kimono is not made of leather, it is made of cloth (perhaps silk)

Comment: An similar article of clothing in the world of Western is a [**cummerbund**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cummerbund).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be referring to a [*kidney belt*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kidney_belt) or *weightlifting belt*:

[image]

(Image source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kidney_belt#/media/File:Motorcycle_kidney_belt.jpg))

These are worn by weightlifters and people whose job involves heavy lifting to prevent hernias. They're worn by motorcycle riders as a back support. In my experience weightlifters more often use a leather belt while motorcylcists more often wear a nylon and plastic belt.